# Applet requests not extending session live

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, applet, session-timeout

This is my first question here so thanks to anyone being able to help.

Let me explain the problem:
I have an applet that uploads a file by chunks to a servlet.
One of the arguments of the applet is the JSESSIONID so it can create a cookie and identify the correct session at the server (tested with *wireshark*).
For each chunk sent, the servlet is obtaining the session successfuly.

The problem is that, during the upload, the session do not seem to get its live extended. If I configure (at the aplication "web.xml") the session timeout to 5 minutes, then the file has to be uploaded in less than that time or the session will be destroyed and the upload will fail.
It is weird because the servlet is executing every few seconds (and accepting the session id), I am lost.

This is the argument at the web.xml:

```
<session-config><session-timeout>5</session-timeout></session-config>
```

The next code (at the servlet) create logs every few seconds (for each chunk) tracing session id successfuly:

```
log.info("isRequestedSessionIdValid==> " + servletRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid());
log.info("getSession==> " + (servletRequest.getSession(false) != null));
log.info("Requested session ID vs. actual session id: " + servletRequest.getRequestedSessionId() + "==" + servletRequest.getSession(false).getId());
```

I am using tomcat 7.0.50 as servlet container configured in a cluster with session replication and an apache 2 as frontend with sticky session active.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
José

Comment: I have tried this property **org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.ACCESS_SESSION** (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/systemprops.html) with no luck. Anyway, the servlet does always call `servletRequest.getSession(false)` with success.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a friend of mine discovered what was happening. Maybe this can help someone.

The problem was the framework used to create the application, icefaces. The applet was placed on an icefaces page but the upload was agains a standard servlet. Icefaces has a monitor for his pages and when that pages are not requested the monitor finally invalidates the underlying session on its own.

So the solution has been recovering the icefaces monitor from the servlet and "touching" it session control.

Best regards,
José